# Android: NullPointer Exception

Tags: android, exception, nullpointerexception, loading, ocr

This is the error that I get in Logcat.

```
04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start                 activity     ComponentInfo{com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple/com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple.SimpleAndroidOCRActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple.SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.onCreate(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.java:68)
04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-23 08:00:07.524: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

Splash Screen Activity

```
public class SplashAct extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private static final int duration = 1500;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        mHandler.postDelayed(mPendingLauncherRunnable,
                SplashAct.duration);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mPendingLauncherRunnable);
    }

    private final Runnable mPendingLauncherRunnable = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(SplashAct.this,
                    SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    };



}
```

Main Activity

```
public class SimpleAndroidOCRActivity extends Activity implements OnInitListener {
    public static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple";
    public static final String DATA_PATH = Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/SimpleAndroidOCR/";

    // You should have the trained data file in assets folder
    // You can get them at:
    // http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list
    public static final String lang = "eng";

    private static final String TAG = "SimpleAndroidOCR.java";

    protected Button _button, btnSpeak;
    // protected ImageView _image;
    protected EditText _field;
    protected String _path;
    protected boolean _taken;

    protected static final String PHOTO_TAKEN = "photo_taken";

    //tts
    private TextToSpeech tts;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //tts
         tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

         btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
         btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    speakOut();
                }

            });
        //ocr
        String[] paths = new String[] { DATA_PATH, DATA_PATH + "tessdata/" };

        for (String path : paths) {
            File dir = new File(path);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "ERROR: Creation of directory " + path + " on sdcard failed");
                    return;
                } else {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Created directory " + path + " on sdcard");
                }
            }

        }

        // lang.traineddata file with the app (in assets folder)
        // You can get them at:
        // http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list
        // This area needs work and optimization
        if (!(new File(DATA_PATH + "tessdata/" + lang + ".traineddata")).exists()) {
            try {

                AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata/eng.traineddata");
                //GZIPInputStream gin = new GZIPInputStream(in);
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(DATA_PATH
                        + "tessdata/eng.traineddata");

                // Transfer bytes from in to out
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                //while ((lenf = gin.read(buff)) > 0) {
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                in.close();
                //gin.close();
                out.close();

                Log.v(TAG, "Copied " + lang + " traineddata");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Was unable to copy " + lang + " traineddata " + e.toString());
            }
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // _image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        _field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field);
        _button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        _button.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickHandler());

        _path = DATA_PATH + "/ocr.jpg";
    }

    public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Starting Camera app");
            startCameraActivity();
        }
    }

    // Simple android photo capture:
    // http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/simple-android-photo-capture/

    protected void startCameraActivity() {
        File file = new File(_path);
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        Log.i(TAG, "resultCode: " + resultCode);

        if (resultCode == -1) {
            onPhotoTaken();
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "User cancelled");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putBoolean(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.PHOTO_TAKEN, _taken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState()");
        if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.PHOTO_TAKEN)) {
            onPhotoTaken();
        }
    }

    protected void onPhotoTaken() {
        _taken = true;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_path, options);

        try {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(_path);
            int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            Log.v(TAG, "Orient: " + exifOrientation);

            int rotate = 0;

            switch (exifOrientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotate = 90;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotate = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotate = 270;
                break;
            }

            Log.v(TAG, "Rotation: " + rotate);

            if (rotate != 0) {

                // Getting width & height of the given image.
                int w = bitmap.getWidth();
                int h = bitmap.getHeight();

                // Setting pre rotate
                Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
                mtx.preRotate(rotate);

                // Rotating Bitmap
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, false);
            }

            // Convert to ARGB_8888, required by tess
            bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't correct orientation: " + e.toString());
        }

        // _image.setImageBitmap( bitmap );

        Log.v(TAG, "Before baseApi");

        TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
        baseApi.setDebug(true);
        baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, lang);
        baseApi.setImage(bitmap);

        String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();

        baseApi.end();

        // You now have the text in recognizedText var, you can do anything with it.
        // We will display a stripped out trimmed alpha-numeric version of it (if lang is eng)
        // so that garbage doesn't make it to the display.

        Log.v(TAG, "OCRED TEXT: " + recognizedText);

        if ( lang.equalsIgnoreCase("eng") ) {
            recognizedText = recognizedText.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", " ");
        }

        recognizedText = recognizedText.trim();

        if ( recognizedText.length() != 0 ) {
            _field.setText(_field.getText().toString().length() == 0 ? recognizedText : _field.getText() + " " + recognizedText);
            _field.setSelection(_field.getText().toString().length());
        }

        // Cycle done.
    }

    //tts
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to shutdown tts!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } else {
                btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
                speakOut();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }

    }

    private void speakOut() {

        String text = _field.getText().toString();

        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }   
}
```

This is my class file, technically, the OCR part of the file is from a sample code, where am I going wrong? I get past the splash screen activity without any problem. I get `NullPointerException,` if I commend the btnSpeak lines for `View.OnClickListener,` I get superOnCreate error, adding super.onCreate doesn't help either.

I am clueless.

btw, button, button1 and field are id of Button, Button and an EditText respectively.

Comment: Word of advice, never use the word "urgent" - every problem is urgent.

Comment: My bad, anyways, I was preparing this for an 'aid' or 'boost up' for a project of mine, which is in VisualStudio, and the submission date is tomrrow, I had this all working except for TTS, I added the codes from TTS and it messed everything up, was out of desperation. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yor are missing to set layout on `onCreate` of `SimpleAndroidOCRActivity`

as **Exception says:** its on `SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.onCreate(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.java:68)`

So do this

```
@Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                //tts//<<<<<-----------set a layout here first like setContentView(R.layout.main);
                 tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

                 btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); //then get button or text id
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the layout before acccessing the child. So,

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not set your contentView for the activity `SimpleAndroidOCRActivity`.

Add the line `setContentView(layoutID);`
below `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Answer (score 1):

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout);//Set your activity layout content first
            //tts
             tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

             btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
             btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        speakOut();
                    }

                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically what everyone is trying to say is that you need to make sure that when you are calling your views from your xml that you call it within the onCreate method itself and not within a submethod, after you set the layout and before the view is used. Put the findViewById right after your layout line and you'll be fine

Answer (score 1):

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
btn1Speak = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

And check if else condition or manage your app as suggested by Er. Madhur dhamande

Answer (score 0):

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

after this assign ids for all the components used in the layout.

Comment: While we already have an accepted answer, and you are not saying anything different, then why post a new answer?

Answer (score -1):

You have to insert setContentView (R. layout. main); after find views, Please insert setContentView (R. layout. main) on before findViewById Views.